# Dotted border appearing after link click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

A dotted border appears around the hyperlink when clicked. I want to remove the dotted border appearing around the link (happens only in firefox). I have the following styles applied to anchor tag:

```
a, a:hover, a:link, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #777777;
}
```

[image]

Link appears fine > click on the link > this box appears > goes off when clicked somewhere outside

URL: http://www.boxleak.in/ritgan

P.S.: Bootstrap is also included.

Comment: try text-decoration: none!important;

Comment: Tried that. Doesnt work.

Comment: try `a:focus { border: none; outline: none;`

Comment: @freestock.tk : thanks this works !!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Anchor links (`<a>`'s) by default have a dotted outline around them when
>   they become "active" or "focused".

Try

```
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Read  - https://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/

Comment: @Ankit If the answer helped you, please consider marking this answer as accepted. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's a default focus style for `<a>` tag. Using a:focus you can removed that border.

```
a:focus {
 outline: none;
}
```